# Windows 10 UWP Bluetooth Connection with Arduino

Tags: c#, bluetooth, arduino, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I was trying to find ways to find and connect Arduino via Bluetooth through UWP app, so with lots of fiddling I found two ways(couldn't find any official MS documentation on that, unfortunately)
So one method is

```
            DeviceInformationCollection availableDevices = await BluetoothSerial.listAvailableDevicesAsync();
        foreach (DeviceInformation device in availableDevices)
        {
            deviceList.Add(device);

        }
```

This returns a Bluetooth device named "Dev B",and it is actually my arduino's Bluetooth module. Even though there are other devices available paired/unpaired this method always returns just "Dev B".

And then I use this function to connect with Arduino

```
            var selectedDevice = (DeviceInformation)DeviceListView.SelectedItem;
        uint BaudRate = 9600;
        var connection = new BluetoothSerial(selectedDevice.Name);
        arduino = new RemoteDevice(connection);
        connection.begin(BaudRate, SerialConfig.SERIAL_8N1);
        connection.ConnectionEstablished += OnConnectionEstablished;

        ConnectedDeviceTextBox.Text = "Connected with Arduino.";
```

And it works wonderfully and gets connected. And everything is good till now

So because I needed to find all the bluetooth devices available I found following method

```
            var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true);
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
        {
            deviceList.Add(device);
        }
```

This gives me all the paired Bluetooth devices, but the name of Bluetooth module is now HC-05(This is actually the name that windows show in Bluetooth setting and everywhere else). But if I pass this device information to Connection code above it doesn't connect. I tried using device name in

```
var connection = new BluetoothSerial(selectedDevice.Name);
```

but it doesn't work, I also tried passing in device itself

```
var connection = new BluetoothSerial(selectedDevice);
```

still no luck.

Can someone please explain the name difference and why its not connecting with second method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first api BluetoothSerial actually operate on RFCOMM device of Bluetooth. You can find its implementation [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/serial-wiring/blob/4af35e3c01fa42331c7f71a3c1d300a73fed6438/source/BluetoothSerial.cpp).

The second api BluetoothDevice actually operate on classical Bluetooth device like Bluetooth headset.

They are implementated different Bluetooth protocol and respectively belongs to [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.aspx) and [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.aspx) namespace in Windows Runtime.

Based on above reason, you pass BluetoothDevice to BluetoothSerial interface and get failure, it is reasonable.

As for the device name, I think since it has different representations in the results of calling two type of device api, so, they are incompatible.

Comment: Thank You Rita,
Got your point regarding difference between Rfcomm and BluetoothDevice class.
As for the name I tried changing the name of HC-05 Bluetooth module, its updated everywhere except for my app where it still shows Dev B with first method. I'll keep looking into this and update the thread if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

The BluetoothSerial class calls [RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.fromidasync) where the string represents the RFCOMM service instance (a service).

The [BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.fromidasync#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothDevice_FromIdAsync_System_String_) takes a string representing the remote Bluetooth device instance for classic baseband (a device).

If you want the BluetoothDevice from the RfcommDeviceService you use the [RfcommDeviceService.Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.device) property.

If you want to find the services for a BluetoothDevice you use the [BluetoothDevice.RfcommServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.rfcommservices#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothDevice_RfcommServices) property.